# How to read specific words and numbers from a txt file and save them in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am doing the object detection and want to generate a ground truth .mat file from 7481 text files. The contents of these files are all in this format:

```
car 0.00 0 -1.82 804.97 167.34 995.43 327.94 1.63 1.48 2.37 3.23 1.59 8.55 -1.47   
misc 0.00 5 2.35 254.24 -2 305.25 7.6 4.58 5.35 2.35 1.35 2.35 3.36 1.56  
bicycle 0.00 1 2 3 1 2.3 4.25 3.1 2 1 2.4 1.25 46.5 1.54  
don't know 0.00 2.21 5.32 1.23 5.25 9.46 4.35 1.25 5 1 3 2 4 1.54
```

i.e., in every text file, there are several rows (number of rows are different in different files), and in each row, the first term is the type (car/misc/people/van/don't know....), following the type are 14 double numbers separated by space delimiter. I want to do the following things:

1. check whether the type is car/van/misc/tram
2. If the type is one of them, then in the following 14 numbers, pick up the 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th and the 14th number then save them in a matrix
3. repeat 1 and 2 for all the text files in the folder then generate a mat file containing the ground truth information

Now my codes are like:

```
clc;
clear all;
DetDir = '/scratch/yangj/project/car_dataset/training/label/';
F = dir([DetDir,'/*.txt']);
for frameNum = 1:7481

detFile = [DetDir,F(frameNum).name]; 

fid = fopen(detFile);

while 1
tline = fgetl(fid);
if ~ischar(tline), break, end
str = tline;

end
fclose (fid);

end
```

I think I should do the type checking and number-picking up in the while loop, but I have no ideas how to write the codes to achieve my goal.

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your delimiter is a space, the `don't know` statement is quite annoying.. I would suggest to fix that first using for instance this nice (Perl) function [`replaceinfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18909-replace-strings-in-text-file), which can change the `don't know` into for instance `don't_know`.

If that is fixed, the following should work:

```
N = numel(F);
C = cell(N,1);
for idx = 1:N

    % get the data
    fid = fopen([DetDir F(idx).name]);
    data = textscan(fid,'%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f');
    fclose(fid);

    % combine all numeric data 
    M = horzcat(data{2:end});

    % check for a string match
    b = cellfun(@(type) strcmp(data{1}, type), {'car','van','misc','tram'}, 'uni', 0);

    % keep only the interesting part of the numeric data
    C{idx} = M(any(horzcat(b{:}),2),[4 5 6 7 14]);
end

% combine and save
gt = vertcat(C{:});
save('gt.mat', 'gt');
```

If you do not change the `don't know` statements in the files, the code will actually still run, but (in general) not result in the desired `gt` matrix.

---

To answer your question about adding additional stuff:

After constructing `M`, simply add:

```
M(:,end+1) = M(:,6)-M(:,4); % this becomes the 15-th value
```

Including the filenumber is done by changing `C{idx} = M(any(horzcat(b{:}),2),[4 5 6 7 14]);` into

```
fnr = (idx-1) * ones(sum(sum(horzcat(b{:}),2)),1);
C{idx} = [fnr M(any(horzcat(b{:}),2),[4 5 7 14 15])];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer...I made a mistake that the 'don't know' is actually 'DontCare', so the trouble with space is not a problem now..However, after running the codes, the exported gt.mat is empty...no idea why this is so....AND, By the way, if I want to save the frameNum in the first column of the matrix (But please notice that the frameNum is from 0000 to 7480), and if I want to save the a = 6th_Number - 4th_Number in place of the 6th_Number, how should I do?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. Here it works fine. I would advise to debug the code and study the intermediate results. First start with a single file and study the `data` cell array: does it contain the data as desired? Next, consider the string matching: is the `b` cell array as you would expect? (The first cell in this array contains an array for matches on the word `car`, the second on `van`, and so on).

Comment: I know where the mistake is..Since it should be 'Car' instead of 'car'...Thank you very much.... AND, could you help me with this problem: If I want to save the txt number in the first column of the matrix (But please notice that the txt number is from 0000 to 7480), and if I want to save the a = 6th_Number - 4th_Number in place of the 6th_Number, how should I do?

Comment: I included an answer to that in my last edit. By the way, using `strcmpi` compares strings case insensitively, so you could change that in the code. Anyway, if everything is fixed now - you could consider accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I have clicked that, thank you very much! Your answer is really helpful.